# Specify Domain Level for Clear-Site-Data / Subdomains

Tags: security, cookies, browser, clear-site-data

We use the [Clear-Site-Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data) header for cleaning cookies and other data on logout.

> If this header is delivered with the response at https://example.com/clear-cookies, all cookies on the same domain https://example.com and any subdomains (like https://stage.example.com, etc), will be cleared out.

Now this is a problem, if other systems run on subdomains.

I also wonder what happens for domains like "example.co.uk" - would that mean that all the data for all UK company domains is cleared?

How does the browser determine which domains to clear? And can it be influcened?

We want to use it on `oursystem.example.org` so that it clears only `oursystem.example.org` and not `othersystem.example.org`

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the [w3c specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/clear-site-data/) it seems like the `Clear-Site-Data` will clear only the specified domain including it subdomains. So if you clear `example.co.uk` it will also clear `system.example.co.uk`. If you clear `anothersystem.example.co.uk` it will also clear `a.anothersystem.example.co.uk` and all its subdomains. Here is the [example](https://www.w3.org/TR/clear-site-data/#example-targeted) that helped me understand it.

So if you clear `oursystem.example.org` it will have NO effects on `othersystem.example.org` but it will have effects on `a.oursystem.example.org`.

Comment: I don't think this was true in our case. It is not possible to specify a domain. We got a response from a subdomain in it also head effects on sibling-domains.

Comment: I tested it once again, it's not easy to reproduce, but it seems to clean the full domain, not only the subdomain I am on on Chrome 94. I am wondering if the CORS header is influencing the cleared scope.